# How to implement Fixed Size Collections(v1) function in v2

Tags: jxls

recently I started to using jxls, and finished son job.
its easy to use.
but I want the each command not to insert new row into my template,
because the template has fixed size rows.
I just want jxls copy the value into the cell,
just the same as Fixed Size Collections function in v1.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the Each-command and create your own.

To support what you need you will just have to change a few lines of code in the current Each-command implementation and it should be fairly easy to do.

You can then register your custom command (see  [JexcelUserCommandExcelMarkupDemo example](https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls-demo/raw/bf8abea25a2e86b2e21d0067b1b6e7eb737a7274/src/main/java/org/jxls/demo/JexcelUserCommandExcelMarkupDemo.java)) and use it in a regular way.

Also you can modify the existing Each-command to support the additional parameter for fixed-sized collections and contribute your code to jxls through a pull request.